# Save a Word files without Changes history

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

I created a Word 2016 document, sent that to person X who made edits to it in such a way to those edits would show up if I went to Review Tab --> "Simple Markup" or "All Markup."

I wasn't familiar with how those would work so after receiving the file from X, I edited directly to the documents without "Accept" or "Reject" the changes. Now, even if "Simple Markup" or "All Markup" is chosen, the changes look very confusing to me so I neither want to "Accept" or "Reject" any of the claim for fear of messing up the version I now have.

I like the document as it appears when I choose "No Markup". How do I create a Word file of this document so that the next person how opens it won't see all the past changes or those pesky left-side vertical bars that show up by default (until "No Markup" is selected)?

Comment: Do you wish all changes to be accepted? This is done in Review > Accept > Accept All Changes.

Comment: @harrymc Oh that works! Do you want to turn your comment into an answer or should I delete this question? (Btw, I chose Accept all Changes and Stop Tracking and I deleted All Comments.)

Comment: This can be useful to others, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To clean up completely a Word document that was worked upon by several
people and now contains changes and comments :

- In the Review tab : Click the arrow beneath *Accept* and choose *Accept All Changes and Stop Tracking*
- In the Comments group : Click the drop-down arrow to the right of *Delete* and
  select *Delete All Comments in Document*.

This will finalize the document with a clean slate.